# js Change variable will affect to original variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I am sorry I do not know how to explain, but the situation is like this example.

After I instant a `new function c`, and change the value `this.i` will directly affect to `a.`

How can I solve this issue?? I do no know change `this.i` will affect to `a`.

http://jsbin.com/iPIkomu/1/edit

```
var a = { c: 1 };

var b = function(){
  this.i = a;

  this.i.c = 2;
};


var c = function(){
   this.i = a;

   alert(this.i.c);

};

c.prototype.set = function(){
  this.i.c = 4;

  alert(a.c);
};

d =new c();

d.set();
```

Comment: If you don't want the object to be shared, then why are you making reference to the same object on every object created by your constructor? Was there some other purpose for the `var a = {...}`? Is there a reason it needs to be outside the constructor? I can't tell how to solve the issue because I don't know what you're ultimately trying to do.

Comment: That is because a could be a default set of variables used for many constructor..will that make sense?

Comment: If it's to be used by several constructors, and you don't want to repeat the code, then either create it in a function as shown in the answer below, or use the shared object as a prototype of the main objects, and use `Object.create()` to set up the inheritance. So you'd do `this.i = Object.create(a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suggest to change:

```
var a = { c: 1 };
to
var a = function() { return { c: 1 }; }
```

and then later

```
this.i = a;
to
this.i = a();
```

Doing the things like that you will be sure that you always get a new object. Using your code you are referring same object.

Comment: Hm ... can you please update your jsbin containing the proposed solution.

Comment: @Till: You're probably not invoking the function, but rather assigning it. Make sure you're doing `this.i = a();` and not `this.i = a;`

Answer (score 9):

Use this

```
let person1 = { name: 'Vitor', birthYear: 1995 };
// ES6 method
let person2 = Object.assign({}, person1);
```

In case of ArrayObject

```
let person1 = [{ name: 'Vitor', birthYear: 1995 },
              { name: 'Mark', birthYear: 1998 }];
// ES6 method
let person2 = Object.assign([], person1);
```

Refere to:
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-reference-and-copy-variables-b0103074fdf0

Answer (score 4):

Objects are always passed around by reference. `a` and `this.i` refer to the exact same object.

To get different objects, you'd need to just do `this.i = {c:1};` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Since "a" is an object, therefore by equating them it passes the reference to "a", thereby making changes in both the variables.
You can use any of the 2 methods -

> this.i = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));

OR

> this.i = Object.assign({}, a);